# Sprite Kit: Is there a way to disable the scale mode and code what you want to happen

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm building a universal app using Sprite Kit, Objective C. This app is aimed for OS X as well as iOS platforms.

A problem that many people will have encountered is the positioning of objects on the screen as different devices have different proportions. I have read up many answers/posts online to solve this issue and have come to the conclusion that there seem to be only a few options available to the programmer when it comes to solving this which is selecting the appropriate scaling modes which are available: Aspect Fill, Aspect Fit, Fill, Resize Fill.

I have tried all 4 out, and can see that they all have numerous advantages, but all have their cons, so none of them are what I am looking for.

I have come up with my own solution for what I am looking for (the following code is from the OS X version, but the iOS version is very similar):

First, I define sceneDimension using a macro:

```
#define sceneDimension 1024
```

Then I delete the SKScene file, and create my own scene using the following line of code:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(sceneDimension * (self.skView.bounds.size.width / MIN(self.skView.bounds.size.width, self.skView.bounds.size.height)), sceneDimension * (self.skView.bounds.size.height / MIN(self.skView.bounds.size.width, self.skView.bounds.size.height)))];

.....

}

.....

@end
```

This code ensures that whatever the size/proportions of the device the app is running in, the top right coordinate of the screen will always be treated as (x, 1024) if the width of the screen is larger, or (1024, y) if the height of the screen is larger.

In this way, I won't have to worry about repositioning objects as long as the scene always maintains the smaller coordinate of the top right corner to be 1024. (This is not the same as Aspect Fit, as I don't want to have letterboxing)

The problem I'm encountering is apparent when I run the app on OSX. Whenever the window is resized, a scaling mode still needs to be selected, and none were the ones which I was after.

Therefore, I wish to override whatever the program does when it scales the screen, by using the line of code:

```
scene.size = CGSizeMake(sceneDimension * (self.view.bounds.size.width / MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)), sceneDimension * (self.view.bounds.size.height / MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)))
```

However, I don't know where to add the line of code. I have tried using this line of code in the function `didApplyConstraints:` in the .m file:

```
@implementation

.....

- (void)didApplyConstraints {

    scene.size = CGSizeMake(sceneDimension * (self.view.bounds.size.width / MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)), sceneDimension * (self.view.bounds.size.height / MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)))
}

@end
```

And this gives the desired result mostly. However, during the dragging of the mouse, it can still be seen that the scene is being scaled using one of the previously mentioned scaling mode, rather than my new function. I also read that `didApplyConstraints:` is called every frame, which is what I don't want to happen - I want it to be called whenever the size of the window changes.

Is there a more appropriate function instead of `didApplyConstraints:` which does this? `didChangeSize:` does not work either, since the program ends up in an infinite loop since I change the size inside the function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to attempt is .AspectFill,  but with a twist.  You want to fill up your screen, but keep your coordinate system the same on the x axis for all devices.

When you are doing your math, you need to take the aspect ratio into consideration.

We are only going to talk about portrait mode here.

We have an iPhone 5 that has an aspect ratio of 9:16.

We want our x to always be 1024.

This means that we want our y to be 1820 (1820.4444~ to be exact)

Now we have an iPhone 4 that has an aspect ratio of 2:3.

This means that we want our y to be 1536

So, to get these numbers, you take (1024 * height) / width

We can now again talk about both portrait and landscape.

Here is how you would apply the math:

```
let w = sceneDimension 
let h = (w * UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height) / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)
scene.size = CGSizeMake(w,h)
```

This now means that regardless of orientation,  when the scene is created,  the bottom left most point is (0,0), the bottom right most point is (1024,0).

Aspect Fill will now fill up the entire screen, leaving no letter boxes, and no loss on your edges

Comment: Yes, but I need to make the scene resize itself properly whenever the window changes size.

Comment: you resize your scene doing the same math when a size changes.

Comment: my answer is in iOS,  I do not know how to grab a window size in OS X,  but  place the windows height and width where I have screen

Comment: Yes but I don't know **where** to put that math when the size changes. Which function...

Comment: well I am sure you can look that up

Comment: I have, and cannot find it. Why do you think I am posting this question?

Comment: no, that is an entirely different question with a really easy answer that can be easily searched.  Look at the first link here https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xcode%20os%20x%20window%20resize%20notification

Comment: It's not just window resizing (although this is the main problem I need to solve). Sure this solution works for OS X, but then what about iOS when the scene needs to resize too?

Comment: why would the scene ever resize

Comment: Are the scaling modes not used outside of the initial set up?

Comment: on iOS the resolution will never change other than switching from portrait to landscape.  If you are worried about having a view that is somehow sizable inside of a master view, then instead of grabbing the screen size, you override the view size property, and apply the math in the `didSet` method

Comment: There is almost never a need to change the scaling mode once set up.  How you want to think about it is you have a box,  what do you want to do to make this box fit the screen,  and the choices are you can stretch the box unequally in both axis (.Fill) stretch the equally box till it hits the nearest borders (.AspectFit) stretch the box equally till it hits the furthest borders (.AspectFill) or just give the box more surface area till the screen is full (.ResizeFill).  After you determine how this box is laid out,  you shouldn't design it to change its state.  This will screw your math up.

Comment: I took way too long to find this answer, thank you so much.

Comment: @JoshSchellenberger What are you doing?  This answer is probably way too old

Comment: I used your answer to make a constant width no matter the size when I am loading my scene initially. Unfortunately, this didn't work when calling the scene again (not through the view controller). I have laid out my entire problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689691/how-to-navigate-objective-c-app-programmatically-without-using-only-storyboard