# How To Navigate Objective-C App Programmatically Without Using Only Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am having trouble navigating my application. I have written a game scene completely in Sprite Kit (all buttons, etc. using SKNodes) with Objective-C. When the user opens the app, it presents a main menu which is built completely in Storyboard and contains a UIButton that triggers a transition to the ViewController with my game scene in it.

Originally, to restart the game once the user lost I just presented a new scene like this:

```
GameScene *newScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
newScene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
[self.view presentScene:newScene transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1]];
[self removeAllChildren];
[newScene sceneSetupWithSize:screenSize];
```

Where `sceneSetupWithSize:(CGSize)size` is a custom method I am using to set up my game. Unfortunately, this new scene always has the same incorrect size no matter what value I send. This procedure also does not enable me to navigate back to the main menu.

To fix this, I resolved to just call the scene's ViewController. I did this by creating a ViewController object in the game scene class:

```
@property (nonatomic) GameViewController *currentController;
```

And then assigning the controller when the ViewController is loading the scene:

```
sceneNode.currentController = self;
```

I then use that object to call a custom method in the ViewController from the game scene class like this:

```
// In Game Scene Class
[self removeAllChildren];
[self removeAllActions];
[_currentController restart];

// In ViewController Class
- (void)restart{
     NSLog(@"Restarting Scene");

     NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
     UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameView"];
     vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
     [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This also allows me to navigate to the main menu just by changing the identifier. It works like a charm except for one problem: it never pops the old ViewControllers from the stack. So when running the app, every time I navigate to the next ViewController it adds ~40MB to the processing memory. This means that every time the user loses and restarts the game, it takes up more and more memory. I attempted to use this instead:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

But it just gives me a blank screen. I even tried to pop the current controller afterwards like this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But nothing worked. I'm assuming that `self.navigationController` is `nil`, but I don't know what to do with that. I would prefer not to use any UIButtons in the game scene. I would also prefer to use the game scene as is without needing to recreate it in Storyboard.

I understand that there are similar questions out there, I have read most of them but none have helped me.

Thank you all for any help.

Comment: get the idea of viewcontrollers to restart a scene out of your head,  you got it right the first time.

Comment: Before I begin to help you, please answer this question:  Do you expect players on different devices to have the same experience?  E.G.  You are making a pong game, and you expect your ball to go from top to bottom in 1 second across all devices.  Note, this does not include left to right, because that is a problem across different aspect ratios.

Comment: The gameplay is only dependent on the width of the scene. Thus, (as you answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499143/sprite-kit-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-scale-mode-and-code-what-you-want-to-h/34570600?noredirect=1#comment99883890_34570600) setting a constant width that the gameplay is based off of that is consistent across devices is exactly what I need. It doesn't matter how different the height is. This is basically what is recommended here: "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/scaling_a_scene_s_content_to_fit_the_view"

Comment: Unless there is some background issue that is caused by changing the view controller versus changing the scene, changing the view controller seems to be a cleaner way to navigate the app without having to wrestle too much with the lifecycle of the scene. It also seems to be much lighter on memory.

Comment: If you only need a constant width, do not use view size.   I will have to write a new answer for that question, because that answer was pre iphone X.  The way you need to do it now is create your scene using a static size that fits the iphone X ratio, then use your view to fill your scene on the shorter bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me way too long to realise. What I have been trying to do is simply change the root view. This code solves my problem:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameView"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController = vc;
```